# what is the content of an initialised pointer?

Tags: c, struct, singly-linked-list

I am learning about C, specifically the structs. The following exaple of a recursive (is it?) struct being used for creating a linked list. This is all from [beejs guide to c](https://beej.us/guide/bgc/html//#cb391-21).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{

struct node *head;
//Hackishly set up a linked list (11)->(22)->(33)
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //line 14
head->data = 11;
head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));  //line 16
head->next->data = 22;
head->next->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->next->next->data = 33;
head->next->next->next = NULL;

// Traverse it
for (struct node *cur = head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
    printf("%d\n", cur->data);
}
}
```

on line 14 since Head is a pointer and it saves the memory address from malloc.
on line 16 next is the pointer but rather then using head.next to store the memory address
it uses `head->next`. This confuses me as `head->next == (*head).next` this means the content of next is assigned the memory address but next is not pointing to anything.

Part 2:
i wanted to create a function for linked list with the hopes of using it in the futhur to add or remove stuff from it. My problem is that it simply does not get called.

[image: linked list as a function]

I believe as i am simply printing the contents of the linked list, there should be no issues with the malloc address leaving scope.
ignore the line_number(23).
Many thanks!

Comment: Please paste the code as text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please post your code directly, not as images.

Comment: You do not *call* `linked_list_function()` in `main()`, you just *declare* it again.

Comment: Thank you @FredLarson ! that is correct! part 2 has been solved

Comment: @EugeneSh. i have removed the image and formated the code. ty for linking that article. i understand now.

Comment: `head` and `head->next` have the same type (pointer to node), so if you understand what the first assignment does, the second is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 0**

> The following exaple of a recursive (is it?) [...]

(No, it isn't.)

**Part 1**

14. `head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`
15. `head->data = 11;`
16. `head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

> on line 14 since Head is a pointer it saves the memory address from pointer. on line 16 next is the pointer but rather then using head.next to store the memory address it uses head->next. This confuses me as head -> next == (*head).next this means the content of next is assigned the memory address but next is not pointing to anything.

`head->next` is equivalent to `(*head).next`. Assuming all the `malloc` calls are successful, `head->next` is not pointing to anything valid before the assignment, but will point to the block allocated by `malloc` after the assignment. For access to the member `head->next` (equivalently `(*head).next`), the important part is that the pointer value in `head` is valid. The probably invalid initial pointer value in `head->next` does not matter because it is being replaced by the assignment anyway.

**Part 2**

```
int main(void)
{
    void linked_list_function ();

    return 0;
}
```

> i wanted to create a function for linked list with the hopes of using it in the futhur to add or remove stuff from it. My problem is that it simply does not get called.

`linked_list_function` does not get called because nothing is calling it. `void linked_list_function();` is a function declaration, not a function call. Here is a version of `main` that calls `linked_list_function`:

```
int main(void)
{
    linked_list_function ();

    return 0;
}
```